# .Net Core : Class Library to connect to DB, DAL, User Secret and Asp.Net Core's Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following :

- a class library with connection classes such as connection, command, parameter
- a DAL with entities, mapper, interface, services as well as a static class that holds hard coded connectionString and InvariantName.
- an Asp.Net Core project

**References** :

DAL has a reference to the class library to make use of its connection class to which it provides connectionString and InvariantName thanks to its static class etc..

Asp.Net has a reference to the DAL.

**What I want** :

I now want to use the User Secrets to store hard coded sensitive data connections and get rid off the static class.

I know I can use the the Asp.Net Core startup.cs to read the settings from Configuration and make use of binding to store them into a class and use DI.

**My guess** :

DI seems "easy" when used **inside** an Asp controller. But I need the settings values (connectionString and InvariantName) **outside** the Asp.Net Core to be injected into a constructor of a class somewhere in my DAL.

I guess I would then need to have to reference the Asp.Net Core project to my DAL. But then I would end up with a circular reference (DAL to Asp.Net Core and the opposite).

**So what's the solution?**

- Have an intermediate library class into which I would retreive the settings values from Asp.Net Core and then pass them to my DAL (to prevent circular reference)?
- Manually recreate the "Configuration process" inside the DAL and get settings there directly
- Or something else that I don't know?

Ps : I am new in development and only have a few projects'experience in Asp.Net Framework so far..and it's my first Asp.Net Core project

Comment: _I know I can use the the Asp.Net Core startup.cs to read the settings from Configuration and make use of binding to store them into a class and use DI_ **This** is exactly the way you are supposed to do it. DI is always setup in the applications "composition root" (which is different for different type of applications: In ASp.NET Core its Startup/Program.cs, in Console its program.cs, in UWP Apps the `App.OnStartAsync`. You **never, never, never, never and again never** setup/initialize your container inside a class library

Comment: ok Tseng, thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can use the the Asp.Net Core startup.cs to read the settings from Configuration and make use of binding to store them into a class and use DI

You already answered your own question with this. This is the correct and recommended behavior to setup DI for 3rd party libs and configurations. If you want to avoid clutter in `Startup` class, create an extension method:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjetion
{
    public static MyLibraryCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(...);
        }
    }
}
```

to register your classes. Alternatively, extend the method to accept a parameter delegate to configure it

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjetion
{
    public static MyLibraryCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyOptions> setup)
        {
             var defaultOptions = ... // i.e. new MyOptions();
             // pass default options to be modified by the delegate
             setup?.Invoke(defaultOptions);

             // your registrations
             services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(...);
        }
    }
}
```

And all the user has to do in your library is add

```
services.AddMyLibrary();
// or with setup
services.AddMyLibrary(config =>
{
    config.MyConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext");
});
```

and store the connection string in the `appsettings.json`.

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings":
    {
        "MyContext" : "MyConnectionString here"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it and my level is too low to understand how to do.. I manage to bind appsettings.json (from secrets.json) values to a C# class.. And that's not a problem to inject that new type into the constructor of an Asp controller. 
But that's my DAL that needs that new type as it uses the values to create a connection to the DB, not the Asp controller...I don't know how to avoid circular reference as my Asp has a reference to my DAL, my DAL cannot have a reference to the Asp

Comment: Move the options class to your DAL library, since thats where its needed ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the ConfigurationBuilder to get values from the appsettings.json file.

It's probably not the right way to do it but it is working with my DAL and Connection dlls.

In case it helps anyone else :

[image]